# Nested form modeling rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am wondering what my best approach to do what I want to achieve. I have completed the railcasts at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised but a bit unsured on how to proceed

Here my models

```
Customer
Book
BookManager
```

A customer has_many book_manager, in which book_manager has_many books. I am following the nested relationship provided by the railcasts but here my model

```
Customer       BookManager         Book
ID             Customer_ID         ID
First          Book_ID             Description
Last           isVisible
               isDeleted
```

The idea is the customer create a new book_description and also set if its visible, and if the customer delete the item, then i want to hide it but also set in the database the book_manager associated with it that its deleted, but not removed at all in the database.

Thanks any suggestion or idea on how to proceed is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears that Book is a one-to-one relationship with BookManger, you might want to consider combining the two. Unless, I have misunderstood the relationships. It might make things simpler.

As for handling the hiding, this is easily done in your controllers/views by accessing the fields you have already: isVisible, and isDeleted. You can even create scopes in your models, such as:

```
class BookManager
  scope :active, where(["isVisible = ? AND isDeleted = ?", true, false])
```

Comment: I can't combine them, but scope are they just views? or can you actually set variable when creating a new book instance and bookmanager associated with them?

Comment: scopes are just views. I don't think you can use them when building objects to be instantiated, but I haven't tried. I was just showing you the use of scopes when accessing book_managers that were active.